# Typescript array of objects with minimum set keys

Tags: typescript

I want to filter an array, but only filter based on 2 keys (`name` & `surname` OR `n` & `s`) out of any possible number of unknown keys

```js
const items = [
   { ..., "n": "John", "s": "Doe" }, // keep - n & s keys are valid
   { ..., "name": "John", "surname": "Doe" }, // keep - name & surname keys are valid
   { ..., "n": "John", "surname": "Doe" }, // remove - n & surname keys are invalid
]

const result = filterValids(items); 
// [
//   { "n": "John", "s": "Doe", ... }, // seen as valid
//   { "name": "John", "surname": "Doe", ...}, // seen as valid
// ]
```

My solution below does not work

```js
function filterValids(items: (AtLeastOne<shortKeys, longKeys>)[]) {
  const filtered: typeof items | [] = [];
  for (const item of items) {
      const name = item.n || item.name; // name does not exist on `AtLeastOne<shortKeys, longKeys>
      const surname = item.s || item.surname; // surname does not exist on `AtLeastOne<shortKeys, longKeys>`

      if (checkValidity({name, surname}))
        filtered.push(item) // `AtLeastOne<shortKeys, longKeys>` is not assignable to parameter of type `never`
  }

  return filtered
}

type AtLeastOne<T, U = { [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U];

type longKeys = {
  name: string,
  surname: string
}

type shortKeys = {
  n: string,
  s: string
}
```

Comment: You'd do yourself a favor if you normalize your data into a consistent structure when you ingest it.

Comment: I want to know if a type array with minimum set of keys is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by using `((shortKeys | longKeys) & { [key: string]: any })[]`

```js
const items = [
   { "someKey": "someValue",    "n": "John",     "s": "Doe"       }, // keep - n & s keys are valid
   { "someKey2": "someValue2",  "name": "John",  "surname": "Doe" }, // keep - name & surname keys are valid
   { "someKey3": "someValue3",  "n": "John",     "surname": "Doe" }, // remove - n & surname keys are invalid
]

const result = filterValids(items); 
// [
//   { "n": "John", "s": "Doe", ... }, // seen as valid
//   { "name": "John", "surname": "Doe", ...}, // seen as valid
// ]
```

Solution

```js
function filterValids(items: ((shortKeys | longKeys) & { [key: string]: any })[]) {
  const filtered = [];
  for (const item of items) {
      const name = item.n || item.name; 
      const surname = item.s || item.surname; 

      if (checkValidity({name, surname}))
        filtered.push(item) // 
  }

  return filtered
}

type longKeys = {
  name: string,
  surname: string
}

type shortKeys = {
  n: string,
  s: string
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? Or you want further constraint on `items`?

This assumes that each item in `items` has the props from either `LongKeys` or `ShortKeys`.

`LooseKeys` allows any key, but the keys of `T` will be autosuggested when accessing a value of this type.

```
type LongKeys = {
  name: string,
  surname: string
}

type ShortKeys = {
  n: string,
  s: string
}

type LooseKeys<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T & {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

const items: Record<string, unknown>[] = [
  { "n": "John", "s": "Doe" }, // keep - n & s keys are valid
  { "name": "John", "surname": "Doe" }, // keep - name & surname keys are valid
  { "n": "John", "surname": "Doe" }, // remove - n & surname keys are invalid
]


const result = filterValids(items);
console.log(result);
// [
//   { "n": "John", "s": "Doe", ... }, // seen as valid
//   { "name": "John", "surname": "Doe", ...}, // seen as valid
// ]


function filterValids(items: Record<string, unknown>[]): LooseKeys<LongKeys | ShortKeys>[] {
  const filtered: LooseKeys<LongKeys | ShortKeys>[] = [];
  for (const item of items) {
    if ('name' in item && 'surname' in item) {
      removeKeysFromObject(item, ['n', 's']);
    } else if ('n' in item && 's' in item) {
      removeKeysFromObject(item, ['name', 'surname']);
    } else {
      continue;
    }

    const name = item.n || item.name;
    const surname = item.s || item.surname;
    if (checkValidity({ name, surname }))
      filtered.push(item as LooseKeys<LongKeys | ShortKeys>);
  }

  return filtered;
}

function removeKeysFromObject(obj: Record<string, unknown>, keys: string[]) {
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (key in obj) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
}

function checkValidity({ name, surname }: { name: unknown, surname: unknown }) {
  return true;
}
```

---

**Edit1**: replying to a comment

Original `items` array remains unchanged, including the items iself. `filterValids` creates a new array, where only items with either `LongKeys` or `ShortKeys` are included (along with any other props).

```
console.log('original', items);

const result = filterValids(items);
console.log('result', result);
// [
//   { "n": "John", "s": "Doe", ... }, // seen as valid
//   { "name": "John", "surname": "Doe", ...}, // seen as valid
// ]


function filterValids(items: Record<string, unknown>[]): LooseKeys<LongKeys | ShortKeys>[] {
  const filtered: LooseKeys<LongKeys | ShortKeys>[] = [];
  for(const item of items) {
    if (
      !('name' in item && 'surname' in item)
      && !('n' in item && 's' in item)
    ) {
      continue;
    }

    const name = item.n || item.name;
    const surname = item.s || item.surname;
    if (checkValidity({ name, surname }))
      filtered.push(item as LooseKeys<LongKeys | ShortKeys>);
  }

  return filtered;
}
```

Comment: This however changes the original array. I want to keep the original but simply remove items from the array that are "invalid" ie. that don't have the minimum set of required keys

Comment: @KevinPotgieter I've edited the code, check it out.

Comment: Ah ok I see you opted to rather make the input `any` of sorts, and rather check with `in` if the right keys exists. This will work and thanks for your help. Though I am curious to learn if an input `type` could be defined with the "required" key constraints whilst also supporting `unknown` keys